# How implement Postgres backups on Kubernetes?

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes

What's the best approach for backing up a Postgres on Kubernetes?

My first guess would have been to create a master-slave architecture with enabling replication. Doing an initial pg_basebackup and then fetching the WAL-logs. Once in a month I'd have scheduled another pg_basebackup with a cron, however containerized environemnts don't like cron daemons (no systemd available). How do you schedule base backups?

Comment: Kubernetes does have a `CronJob` resource type.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

Comment: As mentioned in above comments, you coul use cronjob, [there](https://devtron.ai/blog/creating-a-kubernetes-cron-job-to-backup-postgres-db/)  and [there](https://cwienczek.com/2020/06/simple-backup-of-postgres-database-in-kubernetes/) is an example of that, another idea might be to use [operator](https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator), there is [blog](https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/schedule-postgresql-backups-and-retention-with-kubernetes) about that.

Answer (score 10):

The best approach is to use the Kubernetes [Cronjob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) resource:

> You can use a CronJob to run [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) on a time-based schedule. These
> automated jobs run like Cron tasks on a Linux or UNIX system.
>
> Cron jobs are useful for creating periodic and recurring tasks, like
> running backups or sending emails.

You basically need to create a custom Linux image to run in your container jobs. This image will need a Postgres Client (so you can connect to your database with `psql`, `pg_dump` or `pg_basebackup`); and the credentials that can be configured as a [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/).

You may want to upload the backup to external storage, so you can install and use `awscli` for AWS S3, `gsutil` for Google Cloud Storage, etc...

Here is some references:

- [Creating a Kubernetes Cron Job to backup Postgres DB](https://devtron.ai/blog/creating-a-kubernetes-cron-job-to-backup-postgres-db/)
- [Simple backup of postgres database in kubernetes](https://cwienczek.com/2020/06/simple-backup-of-postgres-database-in-kubernetes/)
- [Back up databases using Kubernetes CronJobs](https://www.orange-networks.com/blogs/208-back-up-databases-using-kubernetes-cronjobs)